# Repeating a Numpy array to match dimension of another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'd like to repeat an array along multiple dimensions, such that it matches the dimensions of another array.

For example, lets put:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(300)
b = np.zeros((300, 10, 20, 40, 50))
```

I'd like to expand `a` such that it matches the dimensions of `b`, considering than be can have an arbitrary number of dimensions of arbitrary length.

For now, the only thing I can do is a loop over the dimensions like:

```
c = np.copy(a)
for axis, length in enumerate(b.shape[1:]):
  c = np.repeat(c[..., None], length, axis + 1)
```

But it is rather inefficient for a large number of dimensions ...

Comment: `np.tile` can do it, but it too does repeated `repeats`.  But does it need to fully match, or is `broadcasting` enough?  There is also a `broadcast_to`.

Comment: The problem isn't just the large number of dimensions, it's the large final size of that array.  I keep killing my terminal when I test various alternatives (on a rather modest machine.

Comment: For your first comment, please find the original issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69433596/numpy-replacing-value-in-array-based-on-a-condition-on-a-coordinate-vector-rep).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reshape and expand_dims can make an array that will `broadcast` like a `b` shaped array

`tile` can expand that.  Check the code, but I think it does repeated `repeats` as you do:

```
d=np.tile(np.expand_dims(a,[1,2,3,4]),(1,)+b.shape[1:])
```

Another way to expand the array to full size, but without the full memory use is:

```
w = np.broadcast_to(np.expand_dims(a,[1,2,3,4]),b.shape)
```

`w` should have the same shape, but `strides` will be `(8, 0, 0, 0, 0)`, compared to `(3200000, 320000, 16000, 400, 8)` for `b` or `c`.

But making `w.copy()` will take nearly as long making `c` or `d`, because it has to make the full Gb array.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with you comment on `w` size. I have `(c == w).all()` which `True` !

Answer (score 1):

One option is to `reshape` `a` so it can be broadcasted against `b`, and then assign values to target array inplace:

```
c = np.zeros(b.shape)
c[:] = a.reshape(b.shape[:1] + (1,) * (len(b.shape) - 1))
```

Or use `np.expand_dims` to reshape:

```
c[:] = np.expand_dims(a, axis=tuple(range(1, len(b.shape))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `np.empty_like` together with `np.copyto`

```
c = np.emtpy_like(b)
np.copyto(c.T,a)

#check:
(c == a[:,None,None,None,None]).all()
# True
```

Or, if you want to retain `a`'s dtype:

```
c = np.empty(b.shape,a.dtype)
# etc.
```