# Numpy - replacing value in array based on a condition on a coordinate vector representing one dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `data` array of multiple dimensions, with the last one being the distance. On the other hand, I have the distance vector `r`. For instance:

```
Data = np.ones((20, 30, 100))
r = np.linspace(10, 50, 100)
```

Finally, I also have a list of critical distance values called `r0`, such that `(r0.shape == Data.shape[:-1]).all()`. For instance,

```
r0 = np.random.random((20, 30))*40 + 10
```

I'm looking to replace values of Data by zero based on a condition on `r` and `r0` corresponding to the first dimensions of `Data`. For example, I want for any `i` and `j` that:

```
Data[i, j, r>=r0[i,j]] = 0
```

Consider that `Data` can be a big array such that using loops is very long. My current workaround is:

```
r_temp = np.broadcast_to(np.expand_dims(r, list(np.arange(len(Data.shape)-1))), Data.shape)
Data[r_temp >= r0[..., None]] = 0
```

It is fast, but it consumes a lot of memory considering that I have to store the array `r_temp`, which can be problematic if `Data` starts to be big.

Any solution that does not necessitate to create and store `r_temp` ?

Note: for the creation of `r_temp`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69418841/repeating-a-numpy-array-to-match-dimension-of-another-array?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Funnily your solution does not create and store `r_temp`. The `np.broadcast_to` just cheats to get an array that seems to be big but repetitive. But in fact you only have the original array stored. If you wanna know more the following talk explains it much better than I could in the comments: https://youtu.be/cYugp9IN1-Q?t=854